# 14.10 Cannot connect to internet through a wired connection. Still trying before install

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, 14.10, wired

I'm currently attempting to install 14.1 on a new computer via USB. No Wireless. It's plugged into the ethernet port on a Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 ATX mother board with an AMD FX-6350 3.9 GHz 6 core processor. I tried 14.04 but it wouldn't even boot, when I looked into that it appeared to be a conflict with the mobo or processor. Right now I'm just running from the "try ubuntu before you install" option. I'd like to be connected to the internet before I consider installing. I'm not super familiar with the ubuntu terminal but I'm not afraid to mess with it. The network works properly on both wired and wireless Windows 7 and 8 machines connected.

Things I've tried:

-rebooting and resetting my modem and router -manually entering my ipv4, it says it connects but I get no internet connection. I've triple checked to ensure I got it right -adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the DNS servers -resetting networking with sudo service network-manager restart, nothing. -pinging my ip (64 bytes from (IP): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms) over and over until stopped

Probably a few other things that I can't remember right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're booting a 64-bit kernel and I think the VIA USB controller driver wants some kind of IOMMU, try booting with `iommu=soft` parameter. It worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Could explain where to add the 'iommu=soft' parameter please?

Comment: 'iommu=soft' it's a Linux kernel parameter

Comment: Sure, I suggested that you could also add or link how to add them to the kernel boot command (e.g [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter))

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas of which I recommend you plan on trying both.  My first thought was that you should prepare another USB install thumbdrive, this time using 12.04, and I suggest that only because there seem to be a lot of complaints about 14.04.  My second thought may be better though.  I suggest you make a second install thumbdrive, but this time the same version you are attempting already.  The reason is that I've seen install thumbdrives fail to write properly.  Use a new thumbdrive, as the drives themselves can be flaky, and preferably download a fresh copy of the ISO file as well, in case it is corrupt.

I'm not a huge fan of Gigabyte brand motherboards, but they don't typically display the problems you are describing.

Comment: Alright, I tried a new USB and my old USB drive with versions 14.1, 14.04, 13.1, and 13.04. I began to try 12.04 but there was no try before install option and I don't really want to install before I know it works. It took a few tries to actually get 13.1 and 13.04 to boot. Same problem with all versions, though. The computer knows that there is an ethernet cable plugged in but can't connect to the network.

Comment: That's very strange.  About the only suggestion I can imagine making at this point, although I would assume you've already done this, is to reset the CMOS and configure it for "failsafe defaults".

Comment: Tanks for  trying to help, man.